# Sum of Numbers (expected output issue)

Tags: java

I am having issues with my program. The point is that the user needs to enter a starting number (ex:1) and an ending number (ex:5), the output should be 1+2+3+4+5=15. I, on the other hand, am getting 1+2+3+4+5+. I am unsure as to how to fix it, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!Also is there anyway to not return null? My program keeps asking me to return it to null.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOfNumbers  
    {
    public String getSum(int start, int end) 

        { 
        int sum=0;

           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in) ; //Scanner used to get keyboard values 

           System.out.println("Enter your starting number: "); 
           start = scanner.nextInt(); //first number 

           System.out.println("Enter your ending number: "); 
           end =scanner.nextInt(); //second number 

           for(int i=start;i<=end;i++) 
           { 
               sum=sum+i; //calculating sum 
               scanner.close();
               System.out.print(i + "+");

           }
        return null;

        }
    }
```

Comment: You sum the total (see the `sum` variable), but you never display its result!

Comment: Your program keeps asking you to return a `String`, since that's what you've declared the return type of your method to be.  `null` just happens to satisfy that return type.

Comment: (1) in your `for` loop, you need to check when you are at the last value of `i` and just output `i`, not `i + "+"`. (2) nowhere do you print the value of `sum` so after your `for` loop, you would just do, `System.out.print(sum);`. As an aside, note that `sum = sum + i;` can be written `sum += i;`. (3) Your program returns `null` because you have `return null;`. If you want to return something else, return something else that is consistent with the declared return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently output `+` after every number, instead output the first number and then start looping (but in the loop, output a `+` **before** every number). Also, don't forget to *output* the `sum` after your loop. Something like

```
int sum = start;
System.out.print(start);
for (int i = start + 1; i <= end; i++) {
    System.out.print("+" + i);
    sum += i;
}
System.out.println(" = " + sum);
```

**However**, since you apparently need to return this result as a `String` you should be doing something like

```
int sum = start;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(start);
for (int i = start + 1; i <= end; i++) {
    sb.append("+").append(i);
    sum += i;
}
sb.append("=").append(sum);
// System.out.println(sb.toString());
return sb.toString();
```

And you should *probably* be using the `start` and `end` values you pass to the function (instead of ignoring them and prompting the user **in** the function).

> I  have tried to add both of the outputs together in the return statement by making them into strings but no luck

The code above is logically equivalent to (but more efficient then)

```
int sum = start;
String result = String.valueOf(start);
for (int i = start + 1; i <= end; i++) {
    result = result + "+" + i;
    sum = sum + i;
}
result = result + "=" + sum;
// System.out.println(result);
return result;
```

It could also be written more concisely like

```
int sum = start;
String result = String.valueOf(start);
for (int i = start + 1; i <= end; i++) {
    result += "+" + i;
    sum += i;
}
result += "=" + sum;
// System.out.println(result);
return result;
```

**Or**, if we're using Java 8+, with *lambdas* like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(start));
int sum = IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end).sum();
IntStream.rangeClosed(start + 1, end).forEach(x -> sb.append("+").append(x));
sb.append("=").append(sum);
// System.out.println(sb);
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: Thank you! But now when comparing my expected with my actual I get this: junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: expected:<1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15> but was:<null>  How do I change null

Comment: Build a `String` and return it, instead of writing the output directly to stdout. Why are you passing `start` and `end` to your function if you're going to ignore those parameters and prompt the user **in** the function?

Comment: There is no need to use a stringbuilder for something so small. String builders aren't needed unless you are processing a LOT of data. Otherwise, you are just going through extra steps to end up at the same conclusion....

Comment: @blahfunk No, you're explicitly doing what the compiler will do anyway (without polluting the intern cache with temporary `String`s).

Comment: Understandable, but considering that s/he is having issues with understanding how this simple type of concatenation would work correctly, throwing a sb into the mix just makes it even more confusing to him/her.

Comment: @blahfunk what would you recommend then? I have tried to add both of the outputs together in the return statement by making them into strings but no luck

Comment: @JaneDoe2 Please check for a new answer to your question from me. I created a method that takes two numbers and outputs the desired result as you are requesting.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help

```
class SumOfNumbers  
    {
    public void getSum(int start, int end) 

        { 
        int sum=0;

           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in) ; //Scanner used to get keyboard values 

           System.out.println("Enter your starting number: "); 
           start = scanner.nextInt(); //first number 

           System.out.println("Enter your ending number: "); 
           end =scanner.nextInt(); //second number 

           for(int i=start;i<=end;i++) 
           { 
               sum=sum+i; //calculating sum 
               scanner.close();
               if (i==end) {
                   System.out.print(i );
               }
               else {
                   System.out.print(i + "+");
               }


           }
           System.out.print("="+ sum);

        }
    }
```

output

```
Enter your starting number: 
1
Enter your ending number: 
15
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15=120
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that will do what you are asking for:

```
public String output(int startNum, int endNum) {
    String reply = "";
    int answer = 0;
    for (int x = startNum; x <= endNum; x++) {
        if (x == startNum) reply = "" + x;
        else if (x == endNum) reply = reply + "+" + x + "=";
        else reply = reply + "+" + x;
        answer += x;
    }
    reply = reply + answer;
    return reply;
}
```

---

Here is the output:

```
System.out.println(output(1,10));
```

> 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10=55